# exim4 not sending email as intended

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail, exim

I am setting up a server that needs to be able to send email from my email account that I have through my hosting provider "JustHost". I have been trying to get it to work with `internet` and `smarthost` options but I never get the email. I am trying to send the email from php but don't get any errors nor email sent. I have tried following several tutorials and can not figure it out. Basically what I want is for my server to send email from my hosting provider email account lets say `hello@testing.com`

I know the SMTP servers would be `mail.testing.com` I don't need to receive mail only send it. I had seen in a tutorial where they talked about ISP's block port 25 so when I try to connect to my JustHost account with telnet using the ip address of the JustHost server it never goes through on port 25 but on port 465 it is able to connect. I am not sure if this could be my problem. I see when I try to send mail from the command line in verbose mode it says `retry time not reached for any host` Can someone please provide me with some insight on setup or what I might be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: It would appear that your ISP is indeed blocking port 25, so the obvious solution would be to use whatever other port JustHost allow. The most common one would be 587; I'm sure that the support staff at JustHost can help you.

Comment: (Also, if you're going to use a fake domain name, the one to use is `example.com`. Don't use any random domain that may belong to someone else, as `testing.com` does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you want this server to connect to the SMTP and send an email which is hosted with JustHost via PHP.

You will have to authenticate via PHP first, then send the email on the specific port they provide (Secure SMTP or non secure SMTP).

If we check at the web page of the thunderbird, they provide the basic informations to set up:

https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/608
Here they use the Port 25 (non encrypted).

You could try to send an email via with the code I found on this website and which include SMTP authentication step (but you can find any other php scripts):

http://support.webecs.com/KB/a390/php-mail-script-with-smtp-authentication.aspx

Let me know if that helps or provide us more information on what you want to do. 
If you need more information, try to run the script via CLI with the php-cli tools.

Comment: I had to use another comment to add another link :|

Also I found this topic in case your emails are sent with the wrong "From:":

https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/206